# SVG filter looks very different in Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, svg, firefox, svg-filters

I have created an example here:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="cloth">
      <feTurbulence  seed="399" type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="10.797" id="weave"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
      <feComposite   operator="arithmetic" k3="4"/>
      <feComposite   operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"    result="rComp1"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha"              result="rColor1"/>
      <feDiffuseLighting surfaceScale="-10" diffuseConstant="0.5">
        <feDistantLight azimuth="225" elevation="20"/>
      </feDiffuseLighting>
      <feComposite   operator="arithmetic"   in2="rComp1" k1="1" k2="1" k3="1"/>
      <feBlend       mode="multiply"         in ="rColor1"/>
      <feComposite   operator="arithmetic"                       k2="1.2"/>
      <feComposite   operator="in"           in2="rComp1" result="rComp2"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha" in ="rComp2" result="rColor2"/>
      <feDiffuseLighting surfaceScale="-10" diffuseConstant="0.5" id="surfaceScale">
        <feDistantLight azimuth="225" elevation="20"/>
      </feDiffuseLighting>
      <feComposite   operator="arithmetic"   in2="rComp2" k1="1" k2="1" k3="2" id="dye"/>
      <feBlend       mode="multiply"         in ="rColor2"/>
      <feComposite   operator="arithmetic"                       k2="1.2"/>
      <feComposite   operator="in"           in2="rComp2"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect width="800" height="200" filter="url(#cloth)"/>
</svg>
```

Open it in Chrome and Firefox and the results are quite different.  I'm wondering if there is a formula to make them the same, like "multiply the k2 attribute in the feComposite elements by 1.8", something systematic. If not, then at least some suggestions as to how to get it to look like it does on Chrome on Firefox (I use Chrome as my primary dev browser, so that's where I designed the filter).

Unfortunately it's a big filter, so there are a lot of attributes to fiddle with.

Comment: If you specify sRGB as the colorspace - they look close. Add color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" to the filter element. Anything with lighting effects can look a bit different cross-browser.

Comment: Simplify the filter so it has the fewest primitives and yet still demonstrates a difference. @MichaelMullany will then tell us who is right and you can then raise a browser bug unless there is one already raised.

Comment: @RobertLongson - I will attempt to do that, though some time tomorrow...  I have a few filters where there are differences between Chrome and Firefox and I started with this one, though I have at least one much simpler one, so my mistake there.  Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Chrome's implementation of feDiffuseLighting in the linearRGB color-space is not correct (on Windows at least). If you add "color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" to your filter element, it will switch you to the sRGB color space and give you consistent results cross browser.

(FWIW - this filter is far more complex than it needs to be - there's no need to use lighting effects when the baseFrequency is this high - you should be able to do everything you want with one or two feColorMatrixes.)

Comment: I have color-interpolation-filters set to sRGB in a <style> where these are actually used. Sorry I forgot to include it in this example.  I am not very knowledgeable with the details of filters, thus the extra complexity.  I found a filter I liked on Inkscape, doubled-up some of it and then trimmed out all the excessive Inkscape attribute settings.  I'll try cutting the lighting effects and see how it goes.  I animate the baseFrequency, but within a range close to this value.  Thanks for the reply and answer.

Comment: I can remove the first feDiffuseLighting element with little change to the result - almost as if I had changed only the seed attribute of an feTurbulence.  Removing the second feDiffuseLighting element makes the result much darker and gives it an entirely different look in Chrome.  How can I compensate for the darkening caused by removing the 2nd lighting effect?

Comment: feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0.25  0 1 0 0 0.25   0 0 1 0 0.25   0 0 0 1 0" will add a fixed amount of brightness to each channel. Or  values="1.25 0 0 0 0  0 1.25 0 0 0   0 0 1.25 0 0   0 0 0 1 0" will add 25% relative brightness (equivalent to abrightness(1.25) CSS filter